# Add a text to an image with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text

I want to create a little site in order to add a text on an image. I've added a textbox and a button in order to insert custom text, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
<script>

function = function1(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var imageObj = new Image();

 t = document.getElementById('text').value;

 if(t == '' || t == null) {
 word = "you forgot to put something";
  } else {
 word = t;
 }

 };

  imageObj.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
     context.font = "40pt Calibri";
     context.fillText(word, 20, 20);
 };
 imageObj.src = "img/image.jpg"; 
 };


 </script>

 <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
 </body>

 <form>
    Text: <input id="textBox" placeholder="your text"/>
 <br>
     <input type='submit' id="submit" value="submit" onClick="function1()" >
 </form>
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" _What_ doesn't work?

Comment: I can't see the image and the text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some mistakes in your code.

let's start with HTML first:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>

    <form id="myForm">
        Text: <input id="myText" placeholder="your text"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

then Javascript:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    }  

    imageObj.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-in-geometric-style_1013-17.jpg"; 

    var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e)
    {
        var text = document.getElementById('myText').value;

        if(text.lenght == 0)
        {
             alert("you forgot to put something");
        }

        context.font = "40pt Calibri";
        context.fillText(text, 50, 50);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**Note**: you need to put your script at the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works perfectly. I'm sorry for my mistakes, but I'm trying to learn it!

Answer (score 3):

By looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to draw text before the image is loaded.

You have to call the `window.onload` function first.

From the MDN

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

Here's a small example.

```js
window.onload = function(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
         context.font = "40pt Calibri";
         context.fillText("My TEXT!", 50, 50);
     };
     imageObj.src = "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/503aeb8a-c1b8-4679-8ed3-da5e11643f29/8a940ebd-8630-4247-888e-c4c611f4f0e2.jpg"; 
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed that and not it works, but how can I insert a variable text through a textbox?